# IntegrityError: foreign key not present when doing a get_or_create

Tags: django, postgresql, celery

I have two models

```
LongJob(models.Model):
    pass

Report(models.Model):
    job = models.OneToOneField('LongJob', related_name='report')
```

I first create a job in a view:

```
job = LongJob.objects.create()
```

Then I pass the `job` to a Celery task and I get or create a report:

```
@shared_task
def celery_task(job):
    report, created = Report.objects.get_or_create(job=job)
```

Sometimes, the `get_or_create` call raises the following `IntegrityError`:

```
IntegrityError: insert or update on table "report" violates foreign key constraint "job_id_c7400e5ba78c00c_fk_longjob_id"
DETAIL:  Key (job_id)=(120057) is not present in table "longjob".
```

After the error occurs, I check whether the job object with the supposedly non-existing ID exists in the `LongJob` table and I do find it. How is this possible ?

The database is Postgresql 9.4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Preamble

> Read Committed is the default isolation level in PostgreSQL. When a
>   transaction uses this isolation level, a SELECT query (without a FOR
>   UPDATE/SHARE clause) sees only data committed before the query began;
>   it never sees either uncommitted data or changes committed during
>   query execution by concurrent transactions. In effect, a SELECT query
>   sees a snapshot of the database as of the instant the query begins to
>   run. However, SELECT does see the effects of previous updates executed
>   within its own transaction, even though they are not yet committed.
>   Also note that two successive SELECT commands can see different data,
>   even though they are within a single transaction, if other
>   transactions commit changes after the first SELECT starts and before
>   the second SELECT starts.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/transaction-iso.html

### The red herring

> get_or_create
>   This method is atomic assuming correct usage, correct database
>   configuration, and correct behavior of the underlying database.
>   However, if uniqueness is not enforced at the database level for the
>   kwargs used in a get_or_create call (see unique or unique_together),
>   this method is prone to a race-condition which can result in multiple
>   rows with the same parameters being inserted simultaneously.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.get_or_create

### The cause of the error

You either have auto commit switched off for your database in your django settings or you are running the following code inside a transaction.

```
job = LongJob.objects.create()
```

You are inserting the `Job` record in one thread and the `Report` in another. But because of the transaction isolation level the celery worker cannot actually see the job record with the `LongJob` instance is created.

The atomicity of the get_or_create method only guarantees that a same report with the same unique keys cannot be created by a second thread. It doesn't effect the object referred by the foreign key.

### The Solution

Commit the transaction before passing onto celery or make the celery task wait on the record being created (the transaction in main django thread to be committed).

Comment: There are some ninja skills here... Indeed the code was running in a transaction, but since the celery call was running deep in the code, I had completely forgot about the transaction. It makes me think I should really learn PG inner workings before blindly using an ORM. Cheers !

Comment: Glad to have helped